# Putting a subscript beside \det

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I am trying to write that the trace is the pushforward of the determinant, and so I would like to have `*` as a subscript beside `\det` in mathmode. But when I type `$\det_*$` then instead the `*` appears below `\det`. Can I change this somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\nolimits`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\det\nolimits_*
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]