# How to get a subscript to \det

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I want to write `$$\det_{\mathcal{C}}$$`. 
But `$\mathcal{C}$` goes under `$\det$`. It does not go to index of `$\det$`. How do I solve it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please don't show us only a code snippet. Always post a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Without I can only tell you, that you should not use `$$…$$` in LaTeX and that there are `\limits` und `\nolimits` in [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). See the `amsldoc.pdf` for more information.

Comment: Thanks so much. With writing of $$.$$, I mean that my statement is wrote in center of line.

Comment: For displayed math use `\[…\]` or another math environment. See again the 
`amsmath` manual `amsldoc.pdf`.

Comment: But \mathcal{C} goes to under \det...not go index of \det

Comment: Again: Please add a MWE to your question. See the links in my first comment.

Comment: I do not see your advice... Can you edit my question?

Comment: `\det\nolimits_{\mathcal{C}}`

Comment: I see that this exact question has been asked before, so I'm going to vote to close as duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297270